# How to search data in database and add it to textboxes in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have multiple *data* in `database` so i need to *add* them in different `textBoxes`.
here is my code

```
private void Search_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = string.Empty;
    if (ID_textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            query = "SELECT ProductName,ProductDescription,SellPrice FROM Table2 WHERE ProductID='" + ID_textBox1.Text + "'";
            SqlConnection Conn = CreateConnection.create_connection();
            SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Name_textBox2.Text = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
                Description_textBox3.Text = reader["ProductDescription"].ToString();
                Unit_Price_textBox5.Text = reader["SellPrice"].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
            Name_textBox2.Text = Name_textBox2.Text;
            Description_textBox3.Text = Description_textBox3.Text;
            QTY_textBox4.Text = 1.ToString();
            Unit_Price_textBox5.Text = Unit_Price_textBox5.Text;
            Price_textBox6.Text = (decimal.Parse(QTY_textBox4.Text) * decimal.Parse(Unit_Price_textBox5.Text)).ToString();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what the problem is ?

Comment: Why are you assigning the values in the `TextBox`s to themselves?  Also, learn to use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection, and are you expecting only a single row of results from your query?  If you have multiple rows, only the last row's data will wind up in the different TextBoxes.

Comment: What is `1.ToString()` supposed to produce?  `1` is not a valid variable name.  If you want to assign the value of 1 to that textbox, simply use `QTY_textBox4.Text = "1";`.

Comment: When you edit your post to add an actual question to it, please choose a more specific title, too. It's far too broad and unspecific. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state what your problem is, but there are a couple of things I'd suggest doing.

1. Use Parameterized Queries.  This will prevent SQL Injection attacks.
2. Use the `using` statement to ensure things are properly disposed of.
3. Line like this: `Name_textBox2.Text = Name_textBox2.Text;` are unnecessary - you're simply assigning the value back to itself.
4. `1.ToString()` doesn't make any sense.  `1` is not a valid variable name.  If you're wanting to assign the value of 1 to the textbox, simply use `QTY_textBox4.Text = "1";`.

I would rewrite your code to look like this:

```
if (ID_textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
{
    try
    {
        query = "SELECT ProductName,ProductDescription,SellPrice FROM Table2 WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";

        using (SqlConnection Conn = CreateConnection.create_connection())
        {

            // NOTE: If CreateConnection.create_connection() does not return
            // an opened connection, you will need to open it like this:
            // Conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ID_textBox1.Text);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Name_textBox2.Text = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
                    Description_textBox3.Text = reader["ProductDescription"].ToString();
                    Unit_Price_textBox5.Text = reader["SellPrice"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        decimal quantity;
        decimal unitPrice;

        QTY_textBox4.Text = "1";

        decimal.TryParse(QTY_textBox4.Text, out quantity);
        decimal.TryParse(Unit_Price_textBox5.Text, unitPrice);
        Price_textBox6.Text = (quantity * unitPrice).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The above code uses a parameterized query - `"SELECT ProductName,ProductDescription,SellPrice FROM Table2 WHERE ProductID=@ProductID"`.  The `@ProductID` is a placeholder for a parameter.

That parameter is populated by the `cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ID_textBox1.Text);` line.

`using` statements are used for the `SqlConnection` and the `SqlDataReader`, and will ensure the objects are properly closed and disposed of, even if an exception occurs.

I removed the unncessary lines where the TextBox's where being assigned their current values, as that's done in the loop above.

Finally, I suggest using `TryParse`, as that will not throw an error if the parse is unsuccessful.  In fact, you could use `TryParse` to show a message if the parse wasn't successful (`TryParse` returns a boolean).

Based on the query, I'm guessing you only expect one row of data, but if you get multiple rows of data, only the last row will be the final values in the TextBoxes.

Without more information, we can tell you much more than this.  I hope it helps.

Comment: There is no error but when i click the search button value from the database can't go to textBoxes. What is the reason ?????

Comment: @user2713054 - There could be any number of reasons.  Does the query return data? Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to make sure data is actually coming back?